# storing active page to server with jquery and ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this demo page where I want to display some images by album.
I'm doing this with ajax requests to a php file called ActionControl.php. Each album is represented by 'a'-tags on the demo page. I do a jquery ajax request by clicking the links and fetch the correct html from the server.

In ActionControl.php I declare a new instance of a object called PhotoGallery.php that contains all the functions I need to call to get the correct html for a album. I also use this object to store the current selected page.

The problem:
I can't seem to store information (like the current active page) on the server side.
Correct me if I am wrong, but to me the problem is that every time I do a ajax request to ActionControl.php, I get a new instance of my PhotoGallery.php, forgetting the previous data stored in there.

The ActionControl.php class:

```
<?php

require 'config.php';
require( DIR_PHOTOGALLERY . 'PhotoGallery.php' );

$photoGallery = new PhotoGallery();

if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action']))
{
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch ($action)
    {
        case "not set":             getAllImages($photoGallery); break;
        case "navLinks":            getLinks($photoGallery); break;
        case intval($action) != 0:  getAlbum($photoGallery, $action - 1); break;
        default:                    getAllImages($photoGallery); break;
    }
}

function getAllImages(PhotoGallery $gallery)
{
    echo "</br></br></br></br>";
    echo $gallery->getAllImages();
}

function getAlbum(PhotoGallery $gallery, $index)
{
    setActiveLink($gallery, $index);
    echo "</br></br></br></br>";
    echo $gallery->getAlbum((int)$index);
}

function getLinks(PhotoGallery $gallery)
{
    echo $gallery->getLinkHtml();
}

function setActiveLink(PhotoGallery $gallery, $index)
{
    $gallery->setActiveLink($index);
}

?>
```

Whats the best way of solving this problem?

Comment: @ADASein so I followed the link and read that the session variable is not a superglobal, does this mean the data will only by available to the current script (ActionControl.php) only, and not on other scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store your data in the `$_SESSION` variable. You would then get something along these lines;

```
<?php
  require 'config.php';
  require( DIR_PHOTOGALLERY . 'PhotoGallery.php' );
  session_start();
  $_SESSION["photoGallery"]=(isset($_SESSION["photoGallery"]))?$_SESSION["photoGallery"]:new PhotoGallery();

  if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])){
    $action = $_POST['action'];
    switch ($action){
      case "not set":             getAllImages($_SESSION["photoGallery"]); break;
      case "navLinks":            getLinks($_SESSION["photoGallery"]); break;
      case intval($action) != 0:  getAlbum($_SESSION["photoGallery"], $action - 1); break;
      default:                    getAllImages($_SESSION["photoGallery"]); break;
    }
  }

  function getAllImages(PhotoGallery $gallery){
    echo "</br></br></br></br>";
    echo $gallery->getAllImages();
  }
  function getAlbum(PhotoGallery $gallery, $index){
    setActiveLink($gallery, $index);
    echo "</br></br></br></br>";
    echo $gallery->getAlbum((int)$index);
  }
  function getLinks(PhotoGallery $gallery){
    echo $gallery->getLinkHtml();
  }
  function setActiveLink(PhotoGallery $gallery, $index){
    $gallery->setActiveLink($index);
  }
?>
```

Comment: won't $_SESSION["photoGallery"] be overridden every time I do a call to that script?

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, but I found I need to check if the session variable already exists. I'll accept your answer if you correct it. Many thanks.

Comment: Oww, yeah sorry. Totaly forgot that. will update it in a couple of seconds.